Taking derivative of output of NN wrt to inputs in PyTorch
I'm trying to build and ODE solver using NN in PyTorch, and part of the model involves taking the derivative of the output of the model wrt to the input.
I've worked on the case of solving for scalar valued functions. In this case my NN had 1 input node and 1 output node. Following some papers, I used
dy_dt = torch.autograd.grad(y,t, torch.ones_like(y), create_graph=True)[0]
to get the gradient which worked. So when I had a training set which was a tensor of shape [N,1], the resulting derivative I got had shape [N,1] which makes sense. However I had problems when I tried to solve planar equations. Now my NN has 1 input node and 2 output nodes. When I inputed a tensor of shape [N,1], I got a tensor of shape [N,2] out of the NN which makes sense. However the resulting dy_dt has shape [N,1] when it should be [N,2]. I also tried using
dy_dt = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model, t)
which returned a tensor of shape [N,2,N,1] from which I think it is possible to access the right derivatives although it wouldn't be as simple. I was wondering if there was a way using autograd.grad to get the correct derivative. Maybe it has to do with the grad_output argument?
